# What is Recurring Profiles in magento and how to active Recurring Profiles

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, recurring

What is  Recurring Profiles in magento and how to active  Recurring Profiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurring profiles in Magento allow you to create a subscription product on a set period. More information can be found on Magento wiki:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

One important thing to note about recurring profiles is that they are a feature considered beta in a few ways. For instance you can't add a recurring profile product (Magento calls them nominal) to the cart with any other products. This limits the customer journey. See this fun comment by the Magento team: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L935

Additionally using a coupon code on a recurring profile product is not fully coded in Magento. There is some work that a developer needs to do to support the display of the discount line.

Knowing these nuances prior to getting started with recurring profiles will save you time.